# My Unity game for Android does not work in Bluestacks

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, bluestacks

I just launched my game on Google Play, it works fine on Android devices, but if I try to boot it though Bluestacks emulator the Unity splash (sometimes) shows and after that only a dark grey screen and nothing happens

[This is how it looks after the Unity Splash intro](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CBYWu.png)

I have tried to install the game though Google Play and by installing the Apk file itself, both ways dont work.

I'm using v2021.1.18f1 to build the game

The game itself is here https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.BrokenGlass.TapNinja

Thank you.

*UPDATE*

I fixed it by changing a lot of settings in the Player Settings, not sure which is the one that actually made it work. Raguels answers was partially correct, but changing only the Graphics API did not work.

[This is how my Player Settings look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZBV1.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is happening because you didn't include some of the supported graphics API in your android build. Bluestacks might not work if you omit OpenGLES2. Make sure you have OpenGLES 2 in your supported graphic APIs. You can find it in `Project Settings/Player/Other Settings`

To make it available, you will have to change the Color space from Linear to Gamma.

Comment: still doesnt work for me, same gray screen as OP reported.

Answer (score 0):

For me worked changing "Optimized Frame Pacing" to disabled, in `Proyect Settings/Player/Resolution and Presentation`